# Disputed non-divisibility of huge numbers

Tags: javascript

This is the problem:
//Given a series of digits as a string, determine if the number represented by the string is divisible by three.

You can expect all test case arguments to be strings representing values greater than 0.

Here is my solution:

```
const divisibleByThree=(str)=>str.split('').reduce((t,e)=>t+=Number.parseInt(e))%3==0?true:false;
```

//It works out fine for small numbers but crashes for huge ones.Can you figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

That's CPU problem.. Why not simply doing something like:

```js
const isDivisibleByThree = (str) => Number.parseInt(str) % 3 === 0;

console.log(isDivisibleByThree('9'));
```